# Is it possible write a custom date format in a way that works for all locales in Java?

Tags: java, date, date-formatting, localdate

My goal is to display a date in a format like:

| Country | example | pattern |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | Tue, Jan 3 | EEE, LLL d |
| France | mar. 3 janv. | EEE d LLL |

I'm using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` to format my dates.

Is there a way to implement this without writing the pattern for every locale?

Edit:  I'll be very specific with my use case: I'm trying to format a `LocalDate` to implement this date picker: [m3.material.io/components/date-pickers/…](https://m3.material.io/components/date-pickers/specs#84872587-cdca-4d06-9906-ed2dc2b35b99)

Comment: My idea is to use `DateTimeFormatBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.FULL, ...)`, parse that string use the results containing E, d, and L.

Comment: I'm not trying to parse a date. I have a `LocalDate` that I'm attempting to display according to rules of the user's locale. I'm sorry that that wasn't obvious in my question. Do you think there's a better way for me to word this?

Comment: It seems to me that `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate()` will give you what you want. Or close enough that you and your users can live with it.

Comment: I don’t see any French example on the page you are linking to. I could suspect that you are inventing a requirement that doesn’t agree with what your French-speaking users want? Java’s localized formats are based on a much more thorough research than you will ever be able to carry out.

Answer (score 3):

Not as a pattern, no. A pattern encodes order, for example - it is not possible to have one pattern such that 'in french' it'll stick the month *after* the date-of-month, and 'in english' it'll be reversed. At best, the localization of a *single pattern* translates names; a single pattern can produce both `Tue, Jan 3` as well as `Mar., janv. 3`. Which isn't what you want.

The method you're looking for is [`ofLocalizedDate(dateStyle)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate-java.time.format.FormatStyle-). This produces a DTF instance that is 'lazy' - it doesn't *have* a pattern, it simply knows 'I need whatever passes for 'medium standard format' in locale X' where X is the locale of the DTF.

There is no pattern that encodes this behaviour.

```
for (var locale : List.of(Locale.ENGLISH, Locale.FRENCH)) {
  for (var style : FormatStyle.values()) {
    var dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(style).withLocale(locale);
    System.out.printf("%s %s: %s\n", locale, style, dtf.format(LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 3)));
  }
}
```

ends up printing:

```
en FULL: Tuesday, January 3, 2023
en LONG: January 3, 2023
en MEDIUM: Jan 3, 2023
en SHORT: 1/3/23
fr FULL: mardi 3 janvier 2023
fr LONG: 3 janvier 2023
fr MEDIUM: 3 janv. 2023
fr SHORT: 03/01/2023
```

Which shows the dynamic nature of this `ofLocalizedDate` variant of DTF.

A thing to keep in mind that DateTimeFormatter is not **necessarily** a pattern-based concept. Patterns are merely one way to make them. That way does not allow you to change what they look like by calling `.withLocale`. Other ways of making DTFs, such as `.ofLocalizedDate`, *do* allow it.

If you're storing a thing in a database or asking the user for something, then you'd have to make a divergent option: The user first picks if they want 'pattern' or 'style', so you store this (an enum col in your DB, or a radiobutton set in your UI), and then depending on what they picked, either store a style value (FULL, LONG, MEDIUM, or SHORT) - again a radio buttonset in a UI or again an enum in a db col, or, you store the pattern (string/VARCHAR/TEXT/JTextField, something along those lines). Depending on the 'style' you construct a DTF instance from such stored preferences by checking for the 'variant' option (style or pattern) and invoking either `.ofPattern` or `.ofLocalizedDate`. While you're at it, you might want that original radiobutton set ('pattern' or 'style') to also include ISO8601 style.

NB: There is a reason the DTF class does *not* have a `.getPattern()` method; that's because not all DTF instances have one.

Comment: You don't think my idea of using `DateTimeFormatBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.FULL, ...)` could work? I'll be very specific with my use case: I'm trying to format a LocalDate to implement this date picker: https://m3.material.io/components/date-pickers/specs#84872587-cdca-4d06-9906-ed2dc2b35b99 Unfortunately there is no format style that matches the headline format in the spec.

Comment: @Sean Your idea will work, but the code in this answer is simpler, so if it obtains what you want?

Comment: My initial question contains the format that I want. I'm only familiar with the expected format in the US and France and I was hoping that I could find a way for Java to handle all of them for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an internationalized application, just have an internationalized version of your date pattern. Depending on the configured locale the right formatting would be pulled and used to format your date.

In case of an internationalized application you are doing this for all the strings the UI would display anyway, so it is a piece of cake.

Comment: This is for a library. Exposing an interface for the application to provide the pattern is an option.

Comment: @Sean (A) A library should generally not be doing localization. That is the job of the app. To communicate date-time values textually, use only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. (B) I'm confused. Your Question asks about displaying text in a Material-based user-interface, not build a library.

Comment: @BasilBourque I have a different opinion from you. There are plenty of examples of libraries doing localization. The Java standard library for one. Android's Material library is another example. It's not a crazy expectation for a library to read the current locale and change its formatting appropriately. Can you see the appeal of not having to specify the format for every locale? ISO 8601 is great for machine readable value, but it's not what a human would expect to read in an application.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's very difficult without manually enumerating them. The JDK uses Locale data from Unicode, so it's limited by which formats are in its source data, for example these: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/make/data/cldr/common/main/en_GB.xml#L144

```xml
<dateFormats>
    <dateFormatLength type="full">
        <dateFormat>
            <pattern>EEEE, MMMM d, y G</pattern>
            <datetimeSkeleton>GyMMMMEEEEd</datetimeSkeleton>
        </dateFormat>
    </dateFormatLength>
    <dateFormatLength type="long">
        <dateFormat>
            <pattern>MMMM d, y G</pattern>
            <datetimeSkeleton>GyMMMMd</datetimeSkeleton>
        </dateFormat>
    </dateFormatLength>
    <dateFormatLength type="medium">
        <dateFormat>
            <pattern>MMM d, y G</pattern>
            <datetimeSkeleton>GyMMMd</datetimeSkeleton>
        </dateFormat>
    </dateFormatLength>
    <dateFormatLength type="short">
        <dateFormat>
            <pattern>M/d/y GGGGG</pattern>
            <datetimeSkeleton>GGGGGyMd</datetimeSkeleton>
        </dateFormat>
    </dateFormatLength>
</dateFormats>
```

The only date format which includes day-of-week at all is the so-called "full" format, and that uses the entire word, not an abbreviation for the word.

With that in mind, here's a horrendously hacky solution that works for your 2 examples, and probably fails for lots of others. If you want to use it, I'd suggest unit testing it with a bunch of common Locales.

It works by getting the "full" pattern and manipulating it a bit.

```
private static DateTimeFormatter getLocalDayMonthFormatter(Locale locale) {
    String localizedDateTimePattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
        FormatStyle.FULL, null, Chronology.ofLocale(locale), locale
    );
    String pattern = localizedDateTimePattern
        .replaceAll("[^MdE\\s,.]", " ")    // Remove anything except month, days, spaces, commas and periods
        .replaceAll("(.)\\1{3}", "$1$1$1") // Replace any char that occurs 4 times with 3 of them
        .replaceAll("\\s+", " ")           // Conflate spaces
        .trim()
        .replaceAll(",$", "");             // If there's a trailing comma, e.g. because of removal of the year, delete it
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, locale);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = getLocalDayMonthFormatter(Locale.US);
System.out.println(formatter.format(LocalDate.now()));
```